# Select 'FAILURE' status records from the table for payment_id which do not have any 'SUCCESS' status updated within 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, where-clause

I have a table with the following fields
`payment_id`, `purchase_id` ,`status` ,`created_at` ,`updated_at`

There can be multiple records for one payment_id. (One payment_id can have multiple purchase_id)

For every payment_id I need to find all the records which have status as 'FAILURE' and do not have any record with the same payment_id as 'SUCCESS' updated within the last 5 minutes.

I have tried group by on payment_id after joining on the same table but I am not able to get the desired results. Please help.

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Those are two very different databases

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help. Also post your attempt.

Comment: Please share more details - if you tried something already, why not share your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow this correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.status = 'FAILURE' and not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.payment_id = t.payment_id
        and t1.status = 'SUCCESS'
        and t1.updated_at >= t.updated_at - interval 5 minute
        and t1.updated_at <  t.updated_at
)
```

This brings "FAILURE" records for which no "SUCCESS" record exists for the same `payment_id` and with an `updated_at` within the 5 preceding minutes.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for your help.
Can you please also tell me How can I make my query faster?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this.  One method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(status = 'SUCCESS') over (
                 partition by payment_id
                 order by updated_at
                 range between 5 minute preceding and current row
                ) as cnt_success_5
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'FAILURE' and
      cnt_success_5 = 0;
```